# Unknown package calc error in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, lists

I am using a style file prescribed by Riton Press to write an article. They have a bibliography format (described in their style file as):

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
        {\frenchspacing
         \small\rm\baselineskip=11pt
         \begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}
        {\usecounter{enumi}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     
%          \setlength{\leftmargin 12.7pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}%FOR 1--9 ITEMS
         \setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}  %FOR 10--99 ITEMS
%         \setlength{\leftmargin 22pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}   %FOR 100+ABOVE ITEMS
         \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt} \settowidth
          {\labelwidth}{#1.}\sloppy}}{\end{list}}
```

However, this keeps giving the following error while compiling the tex file:

```
! Package calc Error: `0' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{10}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{10}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{10}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{list} on input line 1 ended by \end{thebibliography}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.136 \end{thebibliography}

? 
) [32

]
```

But if I ignore these errors, all the references are displayed. It displays the text "pt!" in the references page.

[image: here]

Kindly help me know how I can avoid the errors from the bibliography part.

Comment: We'll need a link to try this out, but `\setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}` is out-and-out wrong (although it doesn't fail if `calc` is not loaded). Looks like a bug in the class to me.

Comment: I presume you asked for a link to the style file containing the above \setlength{...}{...} command. Here is a zip file containing the style file: http://www.rintonpress.com/style/QIC-latex2e.zip . When I use the package `qic` with `amsmath,amssymb,xfig,algorithm}` it is giving the error I had mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that was the one: it's horrible!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 \setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}
```

(tries to) set a length register called `\leftmargin17pt` to the value `\rightmargin0pt`

By an accident of the original definition of `\setlength` this does not generate an error and sets `\leftmargin` to 17pt and `\rightmargin` to 0pt by luck.

If you load `calc` your luck changes.

Comment: Thanks. I learn from your post that the solution is either to not load the `calc` package or to not use `\setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}` . However, I have not loaded `calc` explicitly nor is it loaded on the style file. Is there any way of explicitly un-loading the `calc` package ?

Comment: @PavithranIyer whether you load calc or not you should fix `\setlength{\leftmargin 17pt}{\rightmargin 0pt}` as it is just wrong. You can't Unload" a package once it is loaded.

Comment: God bless you for figuring this out before me; I am also trying to use qic.sty and they haven't fixed it yet. I will send them a note.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem, with he same style file (QIC from Rinton press) two years later, I give here the hack I deduced from David Carlisle's answer : one just have to refine (correctly !) the bibliography environment before calling it in the tex file. The end of your tex file should then look like:

```
\nonumsection{Acknowledgements}
\noindent
I thank P. Iyer and D. Carlisle for saving a lot of time debugging this
\TeX file !

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
        {\frenchspacing
         \small\rm\baselineskip=11pt
         \begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}
        {\usecounter{enumi}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     
%          \setlength{\leftmargin}{12.7pt}%FOR 1--9 ITEMS
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{17pt}  %FOR 10--99 ITEMS
%         \setlength{\leftmargin}{22pt}   %FOR 100+ABOVE ITEMS
                \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}
         \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt} \settowidth
          {\labelwidth}{#1.}\sloppy}}{\end{list}}
\nonumsection{References}
\noindent
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibfile}    
\end{document}
```